# Problems with MySQL 5.7 and reset root password when use mysql_config_editor

Tags: debian, backup, mysql

I am using MySQL 5.7.17 on Debian Jessie and wanted to dump the database using mysqldump with mysql_config_editor.

The steps I did for the mysql_config_editor. They are:

```
mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --host=localhost --user=root --password
mysql_config_editor print --all
```

The user would be root.

Now change the root password:

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

A new terminal is opened and the following is typed:

```
mysql -u root -p
use mysql;
select user,host from user where user='root';
UPDATE user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('123456') WHERE user='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit
sudo service mysql stop
sudo service mysql start
```

Now I execute the following:

```
mysqldump --login-path=local parana > parana.sql
```

And I get the following message:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
```

How could you solve the problem to be able to backup cpn mysqldump and --login-path or if they have another alternative to be able to backup. 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I suffered the same strange behaviour.

When I use in my script the command:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -h localhost -u root -pmy#rootpassword mysql --tables db >> mysql-db_2017-03-17_09-50-35.sql
```

I get the Warning:

```
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
```

So I changed my Backup Scripts to

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --login-path=backups mysql --tables db >> mysql-mysql-db_2017-03-17_08-24-07.sql
```

But that gave me the Error:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
```

The official MySQL Documentation recommends to try the Configuration with the "mysql" command
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-config-editor.html

> To connect to the local server, use this command:
>  
>    shell> mysql --login-path=client

And actually I found that I get the same Error this way:

```
$ mysql --login-path=backups
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I could not make any sense of it until I stumbled over this comment at the bottom of the MySQL Documentation:

> Password string with character "#" in it will cause authentication
>   failure because when strings are read, hash characters are treated as
>   the start of a comment.

That took me to the MySQL Bug Page:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74691

There I found the suggested Workaround that worked for me:

> A workaround is to enter the password in quotes "pass#pass".
>   Suggested fix: 
>   Enclose all strings in quotes.

So I retyped my Password into the "mysql_config_editor":

```
$ mysql_config_editor set --login-path=scripts --host=localhost --user=root --password
Enter password: -> typeing: "my#rootpassword" <- including the character >"<
WARNING : 'scripts' path already exists and will be overwritten. 
 Continue? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
```

And finally the Login succeeded:

```
$ mysql --login-path=scripts
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 139
Server version: 5.6.35-log Distributed by The IUS Community Project
Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
mysql> exit
Bye
```